# Keeping old Gnome 2 while upgrading to newer versions

Tags: upgrade

I turned an old PC into a server by installing Ubuntu Desktop 10.10 some time ago, and I really love it, but it's outdated and I think it's time for an upgrade.
It's specs are the following:

- Core 2 Duo E6850
- 2 GB Ram 800 MHz
- 40 GB IDE HDD (the only spare I had)

My problem is that only the GUI from 10.10 which I believe is Gnome 2.32, offers VNC which works without problems, and is lightweight enough not to lag my server.

How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 and also keep the old GUI?

Should I install Ubuntu Server and then the GUI? If so, how?

I am basically looking to install Gnome 2.32 on a newer Ubuntu version.

Comment: That GUI is long gone. Try Ubuntu MATE instead. Or Lubuntu. Or Xubuntu.

Comment: The GNOME 2.x GUI has been discontinued and it has been replaced by MATE desktop environment. For more information about MATE desktop environment see: [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop/416173#416173)

Comment: Ubuntu MATE looks like what I am searching for. Could I possibly install it on Ubuntu Server 14.04 as well?

Comment: @KiralyCraft Ubuntu server doesn't have a GUI, does it?

Comment: Yes, you can install  MATE desktop environment on Ubuntu Server 14.04. You can also upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 14.04 by following these instructions: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) or else a fresh installation of 14.04 or Ubuntu MATE as Oli recommends.

Comment: If you are really wanting to run an Ubuntu server on an old machine, then the GUI is unneeded bloat. Running a control panel such as Webmin or Ajenti works much better and usually eliminates the need for VNC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have many disparate issues here I want to address.

Ubuntu Server is (as far as is important for your use) just Ubuntu without the graphical desktop packages installed. That is to say, if you want a clean install of Ubuntu Server with a graphical desktop, you might as well just install the Ubuntu spin for that desktop (eg Ubuntu Mate, Kubuntu, etc) and then install things like LAMP (or whatever server tasks you need) with `tasksel` or Apt.

The Ubuntu desktop of the 2010 era is long gone. It moved onto Unity. If you upgrade the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage will pull you onto Unity. You could just uninstall those packages before upgrading (and run an `apt-get autoremove`) and then install whatever `-desktop` metapackage (probably `mate-desktop`) when you're done upgrading the core system.

10.10 has been dead for years. As has 11.04 and 11.10. You'll need to upgrade through all of those to get to 12.04 and from there you should be able to LTS-hop to 14.04. That's another reason for getting rid of any non-essential packages (less to upgrade).

Honestly, I'd be weighing up whether it's not best to back-up and do a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate (or whatever desktop spin takes your fancy - there are many now). It'll be much faster for you and will likely leave you with a better result.

Comment: I am downloading Ubuntu MATE 14.04.02 right now and giving it a go, hope it's what I need. Of course I will do a clean install.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: mate has all these stupid names for applications, and ubuntu mate was made by some osx fanboys. it has a space background, a docker (as well as the default task bar with the open apps which is now hidden by the docker) and usability it low. for example, it has three "software" menu items right next to each other, two called "software updates". the default desktops have massive "UBUNTU MATE" in big letters - does windows or osx even do that? It seriously needs a ux review.

Answer (score 3):

Well GNOME 2 is completely obsolete, and has been since 12.04, but you can get GNOME 3. Ubuntu MATE is a sub-distro of Ubuntu which aims to bring back the old GNOME interface. It's not going to be exactly the same, but it is very similar.

[Ubuntu MATE 14.04 ISO](https://ubuntu-mate.org/trusty/)

Comment: Although it is not exactly the same, Ubuntu MATE was what I was looking for, after all.